# Multi tables update using javafx and Mysql

Tags: mysql, javafx, updates

I have to update a customer information that are spread over 4 Mysql tables. I created 1 Customer class. when I first add the information it is added to an observable list that populate a table, and by clicking on a selected row the information are displayed in textboxes to edit, but the updates are not being saved into the MySQL tables. Can you tell if it is from this part of code or is it coming from somewhere else in the program. What is wrong with my code ?

```
public void updateCustomer(Customer selectedCustomer, String user, LocalDateTime timePoint) throws Exception{
String query = "UPDATE customer, address, city, country"
        + " SET customer.customerName = '"+selectedCustomer.getCustomerName()+"', customer.lastUpdate = '" +timePoint+"', customer.lastUpdateBy = '"+user+ "', " 
        + " address.address = '" +selectedCustomer.getAddress()+ "', address.address2 = '" +selectedCustomer.getAddress2()+ "', address.postalCode = '" +selectedCustomer.getPostalCode()+ "', address.phone = '" +selectedCustomer.getPhone()+ "', address.lastUpdate='" +timePoint+ "', address.lastUpdateBy = '" +user+ "', "
        + " city.city = '"+selectedCustomer.getCity()+"',city.lastUpdate='"+timePoint+"',city.lastUpdateBy = '"+user+ "', "
        + " country.country = '"+selectedCustomer.getCountry()+"',country.lastUpdate ='"+timePoint+"',country.lastUpdateBy = '"+user+ "' "
        + " WHERE customer.customerId = " +selectedCustomer.getCustomerId()+ " AND customer.addressId = address.addressId AND address.cityId = city.cityId AND city.countryId = country.countryId " ;
statement.executeUpdate(query);
```

}

Comment: Learn to use `PreparedStatements`.

Comment: I would suggest first replace all object to actual value in query and also post the existing record from DB into you question

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is:

1. Create my data class.
2. Create load and save methods on my DB class.
3. Set up the FXML so that the TableColumns show the right information from the data class
4. Get the data into an ObservableList from the database (I like to use Derby but that shouldn't make a difference) and put that into the table.
5. Add a listener to the selection model so that when the selected item in the table changes, the selected item is referenced by another variable (say "selectedCustomer" and that variable's data is shown into the editable textfields or comboboxes or whatever. Note that I don't use bindings when showing the selectedCustomer in the textboxes. I just use plain setTexts.
6. When the user clicks on Save or something, the data in the textfields are set into the selectedCustomer (for example, `selectedCustomer.setName(nameText.getText());`)
7. I call the database class' save method (for example, `DB.save(selectedCustomer);` )
8. That should do the trick! Never failed me yet.

However, I may be at fault here, since I couldn't be bothered to read your SQL statement. Please, for goodness sake, learn to use PreparedStatements! First, I don't really understand how your table is set up, so I can't really comment, but it's really hard to understand. However, if I were to take a wild guess, I think the problem may have something to do with this part here:

```
WHERE ... AND customer.addressId = address.addressId AND address.cityId = city.cityId AND city.countryId = country.countryId
```

I don't understand how that part works--either that SQL statement does not make sense or my SQL needs practice (probably the latter).

Since you use MySQL, how about you use a manager (such as PHPMyAdmin or since you are using Java, SQuirreL) to try executing your SQL statement manually and see what happens? If you enter the SQL statement and nothing changed (when there should be) then your SQL statement is at fault.

Comment: It's the multi table syntax here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Comment: Thanks! SQL never was my forte.